# How to apply the window-frame roundTextured bezel style to an NSButton that's not in the window frame?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

If you can edit the title and make it shorter, good on ya. Which is to say, sorry for the title length :P

In the HIG:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html

Scroll down to the section "Window Frame Controls". Buttons with NSTexturedRoundedBezelStyle draw differently when placed in an NSToolBar (darker gradient).

Putting HIG questions aside, I need the darker bezel for a button that is not in the window frame. It seems there is some flag which I am missing.

I can obviously just draw it myself, but wanted to check if there's just something totally obvious I am missing here?

Kind regards,
Alec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Lion, the Round Textured button is translucent, which means that some of the background shows through it. That's why it looks different in the toolbar, because there's a darker background behind it.

There is no magic flag to change this behaviour, the only way to give it a darker appearance would be to place it on a darker background.

Comment: I'm sure I skipped right over this in the release notes. Many thanks Rob!